# Rails: how should I share logic between controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This question must have been asked already, but I can't find it.

I have a `UsersController` and an `Admin::UsersController`. Obviously a lot of what goes on in these classes (eg the implementation of `strong_parameters`, the paths to follow after creating/editing a user) are the same.

Can I - indeed, ought I? - share code between these controllers? Is this what concerns are for? The examples I find for them online tend to deal with models.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: are they really going to be the same? Can admins edit the same list of fields as a general user? Will they redirect to the same place? Seems logical that a user would redirect to their profile after editing themselves, and an admin would redirect to a user list.

Comment: @sevenseacat, in the long term, probably not. but it's useful to share the strong_params for now, now that there's no more attr_accessible at the model level, if i understand correctly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use concerns (put in `app/controllers/concerns`)

```
module UsersControllable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  private
  def user_params
    # strong params implementation
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersControllable
end

class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersControllable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using inheritance. Create a new controller:

```
class SharedUserController < ApplicationController
  # With shared code
end
```

And then:

```
class UsersController < SharedUserController
end

class Admin::UsersController < SharedUserController
end
```

Hope this help!