# rails best way to display button only for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application with `Post` model with associated `PostsController` and `Admin::PostsController` under the admin namespace in routes. Controllers share the same `index` action with controller concern, similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19237378/4612409). I'm using a shared view partial under the `shared/posts/_posts_list` to list all posts on site and also in the admin dashboard. All this is working as I expected.

I'm asking what is the best approach to add for instance: edit post button only for admin user, that view doesn't get bloated with conditionals like `<% if current_user.admin? %>` to display this edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you don't want to put conditionals in your view go for two
   separate views (one for regular users, one for admins).
2. Use conditionals in view and
   include necessary elements depending on *is_admin?*. This is the shortest way to go if the only conditional is *is_admin?* check, imho. If there are more conditionals (roles, etc.) you are right, this will bloat views. You can check [redmine](http://www.redmine.org) (it is a big, open source rails project) and see that it uses conditionals in views too. Check its base layout [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/app/views/layouts/base.html.erb#L31).
3. You can use helpers to generate elements depending on *is_admin?*. Lets say you need to show menu elements in your view. You can generate menu elements in your helper. And you can call the helper from your view. Such as:

*view.html.erb*

```
<ul>
  <%= main_menu_items("main_menu", current_user) %>
</ul>
```

*some_helper.rb*

```
def main_menu_items(menu_name, user = current_user)
  allowed_items(menu_name, user).map { |menu_item| content_tag(:li, menu_item) }.join
end

def allowed_items(menu_name, user)
  menus = {
    main_menu: ["Menu Item 1", "Menu Item 2"],
    main_menu_admin: ["Menu Admin Item 1"]
  }
  menu_to_return = menus[menu_name.to_sym]
  menu_to_return += menus[(menu_name + "_admin").to_sym] if user.admin?
end
```

This is just some quick code. If you want to use it in production, you must make some heavy changes (refactoring, getting items from models, nil checks, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you've got two approaches:

1. The one you mentioned. Your view shouldn't get too bloated, and this is the one I'd go with.
2. You could use the current_user.admin? Check to put an "is_admin" CSS class on your page body. Then, you can add "admin_only" classes to your buttons etc, and use CSS to hide the relevant buttons and stuff when no "is_admin" class exists.

Either approach is fine, but 1 is a bit simpler and immediately more obvious to anyone reading the code, so I'd start with that. Kinda depends on how many admin-only features your UI will have though... If there'll be heaps, option 2 might be worth it.

Comment: Hiding admin stuff via CSS is dangerous.

Comment: You'd just be hiding the UI element. You still have to be logged in as admin to click the button and make it work server-side. So it's not like a non-admin could get admin functionality simply by changing the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need an authorization library(https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

**Gem install**

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
```

```rb
rails g cancan:ability
```

**config**

```
class Ability #model/ability.rb manage roles
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user) # user is devise current_user
    if user.blank?
    else
      if user.role_id == 1 # role_id 1 is admin
        can :manage, Post #Post is you model
      end
    end
end
```

**view**

```
<% if can? :update, @post %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @posts = Post.accessible_by(current_ability).order("id ASC") #posts is filtered by current_user's roles
  end

  def show
    # @post is already loaded and authorized
  end
end
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem that OP stated: *"...that view doesn't get bloated with conditionals.."*?